# Any suggestions on a basic PHP library for doing session management and authentication?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amf, zend-amf

I am working on a project that exposes a number of web services to the public.  Right now I have the serialisation side done (Using ZendAMF) and now I need to do the authentication.  I was looking over Zend Session and Zend Auth and they look like they do what I want, but while doing that research I came across *a lot* of people expression opinions that Zend is bloated or a hassle to deal with.  Is this true?  Are there alternatives I should consider?  I don't need ACL.  I would just like to avoid reinventing the wheel when it comes to basic session management and authentication (DB is Postgres).

Any input would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: In comparison to assembler, ZF is bloated, indeed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, I know where you're coming from! :)

- Regarding Authentication and session management, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975260/basic-authentication-and-session-management-library-for-php) a while back
- Regarding whether Zend is bloated, I had [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427981/commitment-to-zend-framework-any-arguments-against) which concluded in: As a general purpose library, it contains more code than a streamlined library optimized for a single purpose, but the technical basis is healthy and solid. From what I can tell at the moment, this is definitely true.